# PHP Can I prevent asXML() from encoding ampersands (&)?

Tags: php, xml, encoding, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have many xml files that I parse through and need to replace some paragraph text with `htmlentities` and then resaved.

The problem is that when I use the `asXML()` function to save the new xml file, it encodes the ampersands (&) within the html entity.

So this `&mdash;` becomes `&amp;mdash;`

Condensed version of my code:

```
<?php
$xmlFile = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

$paragraphs = $xmlFile->body->{'body.content'}->block->p;
$paragraphCount = count($paragraphs);

// loop through the story
for ($i=0; $i<$paragraphCount; $i++) {
    // Convert paragraph to htmlentities
    $xmlFile->body->{'body.content'}->block->p[$i] = htmlentities($paragraphs[$i]); 
}

// save the updated xml file
$xmlFile->asXML('new.xml');
?>
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<nitf>
    ...
    <block>
        <p style="@Body justified">LONDON &amp;mdash; Britain's this is just test text.</p>
        <p style="@Body justified">&amp;quot;This is more test text,&amp;quot;</p>
    </block>
    ...
</nitf>
```

On a side note, I have a function that's actually converting the `htmlentities` to their numbered equivalent but don't think it's necessary to show that in this condensed version of code.

Comment: Do not convert/escape yourself, let the XML object do it's job.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a choice. I'm running the xml files through a specialized importer with strict requirements (whether they're valid or not is a different conversation).

Comment: The XML objects (SimpleXML/DOM) can not create invalid XML. If you provide text they will encode it to return the same text (including the escaping you make manually)

Comment: What about using some sort of option such as `LIBXML_NOENT`?